# After cloning an element find the original element in the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I clone my mainSection like this (I have to clone it because, there are new elements added to #main over AJAX, and I don't want to search through them):

```
$mainSection = $('#main').clone(true);
```

then i search through the cloned main section for an element:

```
var searchTermHtml = 'test';
$foundElement = $mainSection.filter(":contains('"+searchTermHtml+"')");
```

When I find the string 'test' in the #mainSection I want to get the original element from it in the $mainSection so I can scroll to it via:

```
var stop = $foundElementOriginal.offset().top;
window.scrollTo(0, stop);
```

The question is: how do I get the $foundElementOriginal?

Comment: what's your problem..? what's the current outcome..?

Comment: Currently I just find the searchTermHtml = 'test' in the cloned mainSection and I need to get a reference from this cloned element to the original element in the page. The cloned element has always offset().top = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're changing the content of `#main` after cloning it, using structural things (where child elements are within their parents and such) won't be reliable.

You'll need to put markers of some kind on the elements in `#main` *before* cloning it, so you can use those markers later to relate the cloned elements you've found back to the original elements in `#main`. You *could* mark all elements by adding a `data-*` attribute to them, but with greater knowledge of the actual problem domain, I expect you can avoid being quite that profligate.

Here's a complete example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/womenotu/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <p>This is the main section</p>
    <p>It has three paragraphs in it</p>
    <p>We'll find the one with the number word in the previous paragraph after cloning and highlight that paragraph.</p>
  </div>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    // Mark all elements within `#main` -- again, this may be
    // overkill, better knowledge of the problem domain should
    // let you narrow this down
    $("#main *").each(function(index) {
      this.setAttribute("data-original-position", String(index));
    });

    // Clone it -- be sure not to append this to the DOM
    // anywhere, since it still has the `id` on it (and
    // `id` values have to be unique within the DOM)
    var $mainSection = $("#main").clone(true);

    // Now add something to the real main
    $("#main").prepend("<p>I'm a new first paragraph, I also have the word 'three' but I won't be found</p>");

    // Find the paragraph with "three" in it, get its original
    // position
    var originalPos = $mainSection.find("*:contains(three)").attr("data-original-position");

    // Now highlight it in the real #main
    $("#main *[data-original-position=" + originalPos + "]").css("background-color", "yellow");

  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works! But I am not sure if it is the best solution. My #main section can get over 50 MByte! In the document in which I am testing I have like 9000 of the data-original-position indexes and it performs very well. So I think this is good enough. Thank you very much!
(Instead of writing: .attr("data-original-position"), write .data("original-position"))

Comment: @user3181141: If you assign the attribute, then you're better off retrieving it with `.attr("data-original-position")`, not `data("original-position")`, unless you're using the `data` feature for some other reason. `data` is **not** just an accessor for `data-*` attributes; jQuery does much more work than that under the covers. Now, if you don't use an attribute *at all* (assign by doing `$(this).data("original-position")` and then retrieve with `.data("original-position")`), that's fine, but you can't inspect those values in the DOM inspector (because they're not attributes).

Comment: I get your point. When I try this approach I can't use: `$("#main *[data-original-position=" + originalPos + "]")` anymore to retrieve the original element back. I tried something like this: `$("#main *").data("pos, ["+originalPos+"]")` but this didn't work.

Comment: @user3181141: Yeah, data assigned via `data()` is not part of the DOM, so you can't query it. (This is part of what makes it useful for *other* things, but not for this.) So when it needs to be an attribute, use `attr` to retrieve it. Using `data` will cause trouble (because again, it *isn't* an accessor for `data-*` attributes, it just takes default values from them; if you change the attribute, the `data` value won't change -- this is not jQuery's best API design choice).

Comment: I can retrieve the original element like this:
`$("#main *").each(function(){ if($(this).data("original-position") == originalPos){ htmlResultElement = $(this); } });`
Why should this make trouble? I like this approach more, because the source code doesn't get messed up.

Comment: @user3181141: The source code isn't "messed up" in either case (the DOM is modified, but that only matters if you go looking at it in the DOM inspector). If you prefer to do it that way, you certainly can. :-) Each of those lookups will be much slower than the equivalent selector query would be, but that's only an issue if...it becomes an issue. :-)